# React Router v4 Parallel Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a left nav on my site, when clicked on an item from it I show them a component**(aka. home)**. One the home page is rendered. I have some buttons on the page that when clicked would replace the home by some other component based on what is clicked. The problem is the route for the new component to be rendered is written in home component so when someone click on the link in home components I want it to unmount itself and mount a new component 
Example :

```
App Component(app.js)
====================
<Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Container}/>
        </Switch>
</Router>

LeftNav Container (Container)
==============================
               <Route  path='/dashboard/Home' component={Home}/>
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/Admin`} component={Admin}/>
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/SessionManager`} component={SessionManagerContainer}/>
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/CommunicationManager`} component={AccessList}/>
```

so when I click a button on left nav it renders  **/dashboard/SessionManager**

But when I click a Link in the SessionManager component I need to route to a parent path

```
SessionManagerContainer.js
======================
<Route  path={`dashboard/DialPatterns`} component={DialPatters}/>
```

So I need the redirection to be **dashboard/DialPatters** not **dashboard/SessionManger/DialPatters**

Comment: That was make to keeps this Dynamic, the main problem is all the routes I have  
/dashboard/Home
${this.props.match.path}/Admin etc are in app.js 

So when the route changes to /dashboard/SessionManger on click it renders SessionManger  component which has
/dashboard/DialPatterns route

But when I enable that route on a click event the component dosent render

Answer (score 0):

Just add the root slash '/':

`<Route path="/dashboard/DialPatterns" component={DialPatters}/>`